# Unable to compile code app crashes with this error

Tags: android, android-studio

This error has been shown in my logcat:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol
>   "atof" referenced by "libhello-jni.so"...
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
>                                                                                 at com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.(HelloJni.java:36)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some native libraries the you can use below code for making it look in specific locations. Put it in `defaultConfig` of build.gradle file.

```
   ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }
```